# Evaluate limit of an integral: $\lim_{x\to \infty }\frac{1}{x}\int _0^x\:\frac{dt}{2+\cos t}$

Tags: integration, limits

$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{1}{x}\int _0^x\:\frac{dt}{2+\cos t}$$

Can someone explain to me if it is a limit of type $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or not and why ? I considered it to be one, applied L'Hospital and got $\cos\infty$, which would mean that the limit does not exist, but the answer is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: Thats not an indeterminate to apply lhospital. Try half angle to convert it to tangent function.  then wierstrass substitution then integrate it and get the result

Comment: You forgot one requirement of L'Hopital's rule: The limit of $f'(x)/g'(x)$ **must exist** in order to apply the rule and conclude that $\lim f/g = \lim f'/g'$. As you've noted, $\lim f'/g'$ doesn't exist in this case. This means that you can't apply L'Hopital's rule. It **doesn't** mean that $\lim f/g$ doesn't exist.

Comment: +1 for coming up with a limit which beats the L'Hospital's rule. The hypotheses of the rule are true here (denominator tends to $\infty$) but it is not helpful because the limit of $f'/g'$ does not exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$f(t)=\frac{1}{2+\cos(t)}$ is a positive, bounded and $2\pi$-periodic function. It follows that the mean value of $f$, i.e. the wanted limit, equals the mean value of $f$ over one period:

$$ \lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{2+\cos t} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{2+\cos t} = I $$
and through the substitution $t\mapsto 2t$ we have:
$$ I = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dt}{1+2\cos^2(t)}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dt}{1+2\cos^2(t)} $$
then by setting $t=\arctan(u)$:
$$ I = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{3+u^2}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}.$$

Comment: where is the $1/x$ of the question?

Comment: @RafaelWagner: the (integral) mean value of a bounded, continuous, $2\pi$-periodic function is its mean value over $(0,2\pi)$, that is quite trivial. Typo fixed.

Comment: Where can I find proof that this works for a positive, bounded, $2\pi$.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Because it is bounded, and furthermore, periodic.  Note that: $$\int_0^x\frac{dt}{2+\cos(t)}=ax'+\int_0^{x'}\frac{dt}{2+\cos(t)}$$where $a=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{2+\cos(t)}$. and $x'=x\pmod{2\pi}$.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla: the average value of $\cos x$ is zero hence the average value of $\cos(x)+2$ is $2$. Assume that $x=2\pi k+\tau$ and a $2\pi$-periodic bounded function has mean value over its period equal to $M$. Then $$\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt = \frac{1}{2\pi k+\tau}(2\pi k M+ B)$$ approaches $M$ as $x\to +\infty$.

Comment: Why is $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dt}{1+2\cos^2(t)}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dt}{1+2\cos^2(t)}$ and how did you write the $\cos$ after substitution with $\arctan$

Comment: @Liviu: $\cos^2(x)$ is a symmetric function with respect to $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\cos^2\arctan(t) = \frac{1}{t^2+1}$ is a useful trigonometric identity.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding to my question @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: You actually showed that a result is "quite trivial" by proving it in comments. It it were non-trivial it would need an answer. +1 for your answer as well as the comments dealing with the trivial result.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I stil don't understand the $\cos^2(x)$ part... I understood that $\cos(x)=\cos(-x)$ and that $\cos^2(x)$ is symmetric with respect to $x = \pi/2$ but why is that $2 \cdot$ in front of the integral  ? Can you explain when this applies and how it's done, please ?

Comment: @Liviu: if $f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)=f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+x\right)$, then $$\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)\,dx = 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} f(x)\,dx.$$ Draw a graph and shade some regions: it will become obvious.